# Meaning of "a homicide in Palermo is news"

Tags: meaning

> “Palermo, in the 1980s, counted a dead person a day, they were so common people were almost used to them. Now, **a homicide in Palermo is news**,” he says.

Source: [How the Mafia's Murder of an Italian Prosecutor Became a Turning Point in Italy's Fight Against the Mob](https://www.newsweek.com/italy-mafia-mob-sicily-murder-prosecutor-giovanni-falcone-613971)

I am a little bit puzzled by the bolded part in the above sentence. I presume that the author wants to say that murders are in current Palermo a rare phenomenon. Does the word "news" have such a meaning in the context of my sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

News can mean "something that is unusual, interesting or important". A dog biting a man is not news; a man biting a dog is news. In the 1980s, murders in Palermo were everyday events. Now they are not.

> 5. uncountable noun
>      If you say that someone or something is news, you mean that they are considered to be interesting and important at the
>      moment, and that people want to hear about them on the radio and
>      television and in newspapers.
>      [informal] 
>      A murder was big news. If you
>      are a celebrity, you are headline news.

[News (Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/news)

Comment: I think you mean **un**usual.